# Need to Learn javaScript form validation!

Tags: javascript

i want to learn a bit about javaScript form validation(coding and as well as theory).Can you give me the links for the tutorials(apart from w3schools). And make sure that i dont to learn in depth, because i need to learn this for exam purposes only, not for my feature use.

Comment: You want us to make sure that you don't learn too much? That sounds somehow funny :o) What do you know already? I'm pretty sure you tried Google already (and if not you should!).

Comment: Ya, i know java and started with groovy(past one week). And i have to read these javascripts according to my university syllabus. So i need to know a bit about form validation. As i'm learning Groovy, my next step will be learning Grails(for web apps) so no need to learn javascript all way again! as these can be done easily in grails :-) So could you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classical simple case of form validation:

1. there is .js function that returns false or true
2. this .js function is called on submit action of form
3. if valiation is NOT OK,that submit is not performed ,due to .js returned false

.js(validation of e-mail):

```
function validator(){
var reg = ".+@.+\\.[a-z]+";

    if (document.getElementById('inputId').innerHTML().match(reg)){
           return true;
    } else (return false);
      }
```

.html:

```
<form onsubmit="return validator();">    
...
</form>
```

You may start with variation of this case

Answer (score 1):

There is no "JavaScript form validation" as a single feature. If you want to use plain JavaScript you have to do all the work yourself.

- Iterating your Form Elements
- Checking if they are valid (depending on their type)
- and generating User Feedback if not.

the javascript knowledge that you need for that is pretty basic.

A really great location where you can find all information you need to know is the Mozilla JavaScript Guide.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

btw: its devided in useful chapters so if you dont want to, you dont have to learn that in depth. (But i would recommend it).